# If $\frac\pi2\lt\theta\lt\pi$, find the number of solutions of $x^2+x+\frac{\cos\theta}2=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, quadratics

> If $\frac\pi2\lt\theta\lt\pi$, find the number of solutions of $x^2+x+\frac{\cos\theta}2=0$

$\cos\theta$ varies between $-1$ to $0$. Thus, $x^2+x$ should vary between $0$ to $\frac12$.

Thus, I think the number of solutions are infinite. But the answer given is $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: the solution sought are in $x$ and this is a quadratic equation. Thus the number of solutions depends on the usual sign of the discriminant $\Delta$... can you take it from here?

Comment: For any particular $\theta$, we'll get maximum two solutions. But since $\theta$ is varying, shouldn't we say there can be many values of $x$?

Comment: Or, perhaps, it is to be assumed that there is one particular value of $\theta$. After all, they haven't said for *every $\theta$ in $\frac\pi2\lt\theta\lt\pi$*.